# trasform csv to xml file genertaion using xslt programing

Tags: csv

I would like to generate xml file from an extisng csv file using xslt.

Can anybody tell me command to use.

I don't knwo the command to convert the file.

Suppose my csv file named :- source.csv
ouput template :-             temp.xsl

command:-
msxsl source.csv temp.xsl -o result.xml

Is this the right command or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a XSL file to convert CSV to XML: http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html

To run it from the command line, the instructions say to download [Saxon](http://saxon.sf.net/) and use:

```
java -cp saxon.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -o output.xml -it main csv-to-xml.xslt pathToCSV=file:/C:/dev/test.csv
```

Here are the parts of that command line explained:

- `java` The java executable (programming language in which Saxon is written
- `-cp saxon.jar`  saxon.jar contains the XSLT code, -cp stands for "classpath" and tells java how to find it
- `-o output.xml` Where the output should go.  That is `result.xml` in your example.
- `-it main csv-to-xml.xslt` specify the xslt file (csv-to-xml.xslt) and the entry point within it (main)
- `pathToCSV=file:/C:/dev/test.csv` your input csv file (source.csv in your example, but formatted as a url)

Comment: there are two template given in the link .How I can match them with the command mentioned here

Comment: I am not bale to understand the following option in comand mentioned above:-what it stand for and from where I can found the file named 
"net.sf.saxon.Transform"
what it stand for "main"

Comment: saxon.jar contains a bunch of classes that implement the XSLT transformations. The package net.sf.saxon.Transform is the interface in the jar file, and it is invoked using main. The only parameter you need to be concerned with is the final one, the path to your input file.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have sufficient reputation to comment on Stephen's answer.

- the transform as described is highly dependent on the XSL stylesheet which defines a parameter pathToCSV and a template with the identifier of "main"
- the command will not work as Stephen has written it for version 9 of the Home Edition; when I attempt to run the command as written I get a response of "Command line option -o requires a value". However, this format of the command works as of the day of this posting:

  java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -o:csvfile.xml -it:main "csv2xml.xsl" pathToCSV="csvfile.csv"
- the linked xsl appears to be buggy (probably hasn't been maintained) and will not correctly transform all csv files (e.g. the csv example from Michael Kay's book). However, it is a good example from which to learn.